# InvalidCookieDomainException when injecting a cookie with robotframework on firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to automatise some testing using robot framework. In some of the test cases, I have to inject cookies to the webdriver (only firefox for now). My injection code inside the test case is like:

```
Access MyDomain
   [Documentation]  Open browser in sub.mydomain.com and inject cookies.
   [Arguments]  ${pdata}
   ${json_str} =  Get File  ${pdata}
   ${json_data} =  evaluate  json.loads('''${json_str}''')  json
   Open Browser  https://sub.mydomain.com  browser=ff
   Wait Until Page Contains  Welcome to mydomain
   FOR  ${cookie}  IN  @{json_data["cookies"]}
        add cookie  ${cookie['name']}  ${cookie['value']}  path = ${cookie['path']}  domain = ${cookie['domain']}
   END
```

Some of the cookies have domain "*sub.mydomain.com*" and some have "*.mydomain.com*". For the second ones, RobotFramework results in **InvalidCookieDomainException**.

However, the following python code works perfectly OK directly on the same Firefox Selenium WebDriver:

```
import json, time

from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxProfile

def inject_cookies_to_firefox(domain, dataCookies = None):
    cookies_objects = []

    if dataCookies:
        mcookies= json.loads(dataCookies)
        if "cookies" in mcookies:
            cookies = credentials["cookies"]
            for cookie in cookies:
                cookies_objects.append({
                         'path': cookie.get("path"),
                         'domain': cookie.get("domain"),
                         'name': cookie.get("name"),
                         "value": cookie.get("value")}
                )
        else:
            return -1
    else:
        return -1

    ff_profile = FirefoxProfile()
    driver = Firefox(ff_profile)
    driver.get(domain)
    for item in cookies_objects:
        try:
            driver.add_cookie(item)
        except:
            print(f"Error injecting cookie: {item}")
            return -1
    print("Cookies injected.")
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()
    return ff_profile.path
```

With the same URL open in the browser (https://sub.mydomain.com), this code injects cookies with domain = "sub.mydomain.com" and cookies with domain = ".mydomain.com" without any exception.

What is the difference?, is RF not using exactly the same Selenium Webdriver code? or ...?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [SeleniumLibrary GitHub](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary) source code for [Add Cookie](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/src/SeleniumLibrary/keywords/cookie.py#L116)?

Comment: Yes, this is the first thing that I did, it just calls self.driver.add_cookie(new_cookie) , which seems to be basically the same as my python code above, assuming that self.driver actually points to the selenium webdriver, which I assume that it does. I guess that this assumption is not correct, since it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, "take a lot of care with spaces in RF". Instead of

```
add cookie  ${cookie['name']}  ${cookie['value']}  path = ${cookie['path']}  domain = ${cookie['domain']}
```

use:

```
add cookie  ${cookie['name']}  ${cookie['value']}  path=${cookie['path']}  domain=${cookie['domain']}
```

A stupid "newby" mistake from my side.